# Only static members can be accessed in initializers - Completer<GoogleMapController> (Flutter with Google Maps)

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

I encountered an error while passing a map controller to my Custom widget. How can I solve this error message?

I already tried instantiating the controller inside the initState(){} but it does not seem to work.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> mapController;

  LocationData currentLocation;
  var location = new Location();

  currentLocationCheck() async {...
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    currentLocationCheck();
    mapController = Completer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(.....
    );
  }
```

The error message is passed to the List widget. This List widget is then used inside the Scaffold Widget

```
  List<Widget> customItemList = [
    SizedBox(width: 10),
    customListItemBox(
      photoUrl:
          "http://marjsia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/P1100993-1024x683.jpg",
      title: "Glorietta 2",
      description: "Glorietta 2 J.Co Donuts",
      latitude: 14.550664464,
      longitude: 121.021833246,
      mapController: mapController, 
    ),

  ];
}

Widget customListItemBox(
    {String photoUrl,
    String title,
    String description,
    double latitude,
    double longitude,
    Completer mapController}) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      _goToLocation(latitude, longitude, mapController);
    },
    child: Padding(.....
    ),
  );
}
```

This is the function that uses the controller

```
Future<void> _goToLocation(
    double latitude, double longitude, Completer mapController) async {
  final GoogleMapController controller = await mapController.future;
  controller.animateCamera(
    CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
      CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        zoom: 15,
        tilt: 50.0,
        bearing: 45,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can init customItemList in initState()

```
class SearchResultsState extends State<Map> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  List<Widget> customItemList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //_controller = Completer();

    customItemList = [
      SizedBox(width: 10),
      customListItemBox(
        photoUrl:
        "http://marjsia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/P1100993-1024x683.jpg",
        title: "Glorietta 2",
        description: "Glorietta 2 J.Co Donuts",
        latitude: 14.550664464,
        longitude: 121.021833246,
        mapController: _controller,
      ),

    ];
  }
```